# Don't forget to mention.... SQL injection!

Tags: discussion, data-dump, data-explorer

I've thought for a long time that answers that mention SQL injection get upvoted a lot, even if SQL injection is entirely unrelated to the question.  It looks like the [new data browser](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1270) supports that conclusion:

```
MentionsInjection    RepGainPerPost
0                    57
1                    122
```

Are there similiar "hot words" for other tags?  Maybe mentioning buffer overflow attacks for the `C` tag?

Comment: I *cannot believe* that there doesn't seem to be any difference when mentioning jQuery in the `javascript` tag!  Myth Busted!

Comment: Parametrized query: http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1298

Comment: @Bill: That was the first thing I tried.

Comment: I know this may be a "fun" question, but I still have to mention that correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: +1 because SQL injection is a very important issue.

Comment: Parameterized query that takes accepted answer and community wiki into account: http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1330

Comment: Doesn't this query return the average answer score if the **question** contains the keyword? Is that intentional?

Comment: @sth: Looks like you're right!  Here's an amended version: http://cloudexchange.cloudapp.net/stackoverflow/q/1378  Funnily enough, this actually disproves my suspicion!  Great :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It may be *premature optimization*, but watch out for *SQL injection*!
If you read *Code Complete* you will be prepared.

If all fails, you can ask *Jon Skeet* for help!

Comment: +1 Resistance is futile!

Comment: Needs more generics.

Comment: Needs more jQuery!

Comment: The data does not support that argument @questions

Comment: @Juan who are you, and what have you done to Downvoter?

Comment: Other sites were copying my meta profile (highest reputation) and got tired of editing them manually, I may revert that decision though (in a month when I can change it back) @que

Comment: @Questions your one to talk about name changes! (I was there to witness that one though!)

Comment: @Juan I really dislike your profile page now :(

Comment: @Juan: what if I want to parse HTML with regex?

Comment: It just wasn't funny anymore @ear @mouth @nose... I'll need to think something new for next month

Comment: @Earlz I have no idea what you are talking about. I was born this way. You must be confusing me with somebody else.

Answer (score 14):

On Meta, not tag-restricted.

```
MentionsUnicorn      RepGainPerPost
0                    453
1                    1146
```

Comment: The average post on meta gains 453 rep, even without mentioning unicorns?  That doesn't sound right...

Comment: I think Pollyanna should be excluded from the average @Rob

Answer (score 12):

People like cursing:

Subjective Tag:

```
Mentions F*ck:            Rep Gain
Yes                       3136
No                        880

Mentions D*mn:            Rep Gain
Yes                       2387
No                        879

Mentions Sh*t:            Rep Gain
Yes                       1139
No                        881
```

Answer (score 11):

Java Tag:

```
Mentions C++       RepGain
0                   65
1                   150
```

Java devs secretly love C++.

Python Tag:

```
Mentions Ruby       RepGain
0                   83
1                   182
```

Same for Python devs.

This pattern continues for every competing language pair I tried.

---

<sub>Added because I got curious:</sub>

Ruby Tag:

```
Mentions Python     RepGain
0                   67
1                   115
```

Comment: +1 The grass is always greener on the other side!

Answer (score 7):

The phrase "premature optimization" in the `algorithm` tag:

```
MentionsKnuth        RepGainPerPost
0                    121
1                    387
```

Answer (score 5):

As I already pointed out several times, mere mentioning `SQL Injection` is not enough.

To get the real rep gain, you should hotlink **Exploits of a Mom**:

[image]

[Prooflink](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1470):

```
MentionsInjection    RepGainPerPost
0                    57
1                    423
```

Comment: I don't know how much more succinct an explanation you provide without referencing LittleBobbyTables.

Answer (score 4):

If asked for `books` of any kind, the answer to collect upvotes is always "Code Complete":

```
CodeComplete        RepGainPerPost
0                   216
1                   2529
```

Comment: You can also mention the Dragon Book - of course the people recommending it will never have as much as opened it.

Comment: Why would I try to open it? My door would slam shut.

Answer (score 3):

`[c#]` developers love monads:

```
Mentions "Monad"      RepGain
YES                   164
NO                    67
```

`[haskell]` developers don't:

```
Mentions "Monad"      RepGain
YES                   117
NO                    149
```

Answer (score 3):

Always refer to the documentation when you're asking/answering .NET questions:

```
MentionsMSDN    RepGain
0               78
1               125
```

(Tags: {`c#`, `.net`}, Keyword: `msdn`)

Answer (score 3):

(*In addition to [balpha's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection/51475#51475)*)

Here on Meta (for all tags):

```
MentionsWaffles     RepGainPerPost
YES                 1204
NO                  454
```

```
MentionsPonies      RepGainPerPost
YES                 1343
NO                  454
```

Comment: That's like getting a triple-word score in Scrabble.

Answer (score 2):

When posting on Meta, don't forget to link to the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/):

```
MentionsSOBlog    RepGain
0                 200
1                 939
```

([query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/q/1546))

---

Actually, [*any* blog will do](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/q/1548):

```
MentionsBlog    RepGain
0               186
1               701
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML tag:

```
MentionsRegex  RepGain
0              61
1              78
```

C# tag

```
MentionsLippert  RepGain
0                67
1                152
```

Comment: If you take out the 30000+ points counted for a certain answer we all know, it looks like mentioning regex might almost hurt your chances in html questions.  There's hope for the species after all.

Answer (score 1):

In `[iphone]` mentions `android`:

```
Mentionsandroid PostCount RepGain
0               18085     44
1               137       73
```

In `[android]` mentions `iphone`:

```
Mentionsiphone PostCount RepGain
0              5131      35
1              142       78
```

---

[Conclusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection/51514#51514) considering also [@Justin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection/51477#51477)'s answer:

**Always mention the competing product if you want to double the expected rep gain**

e.g. "Have you tried asking in ExpertsExchange?" :p

---

(Edit: Changed to use [query #1378](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/1378) for the correct result.)

Answer (score 1):

Even more curious are the converses of this.

```
Tag      C#
keyword  "sql server"
yes:     49
No:      67
```

```
Tag      assembly
keyword  "c"
yes:     101
No:      168
```

Comment: I don't think `c` will have any meaning. A word like `accumulator` matches `%c%` already.

Comment: @Kenny are you sure? I find it hard to imagine there are so many answers without at least one `c` in them.

Comment: @Questions: Because the 1270 is counts only questions. Use the query 1378.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, mentioning "mvc" only makes a small difference for `asp.net`:

```
Mentions "mvc"      RepGain
YES                   59
NO                    46
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can gain lots of rep from being anti-SQL.

`SQL` tag, searching for `nosql`:

```
MentionsNoSql  RepGain
0              57
1              129
```

If you can't stomach that, then at least be sure to mention normalization (`normaliz%`) in any `database`-related question:

```
MentionsNormalization  RepGain
0                      66
1                      128
```

Comment: I spent a few months as the top ranked sql user, and I don't think I've mentioned nosql more than twice.

Comment: @Joel: Then just think about how much *more* rep you would have gained if you had mentioned it in every post!

Answer (score 1):

I have one thing to say. Actually it has already been said for me. http://xkcd.com/552/. That is all.

Comment: @mmyers: damn you for beating me to it in the comments.

Comment: I considered searching for how much impact xkcd had, but the data didn't appreciate such an expensive query.

Comment: [xkcd 552 explained](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/552:_Correlation)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works right, but whatever.

Tag is `[sql]`

```
Mentions "meatball"  RepGainPerPost
0                    57
1                    92
```