# Vote count before and after split is inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-count

On [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection/51482#51482) to a recent question here in meta it shows a score of `6`.  But if you click the vote count to split it, it shows `+8/-3`. (`5`)

This happens every time I reload the page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/you-can-deduce-how-many-flags-a-post-has and all related posts.

Comment: It's pointing out the same bug I guess.  But You would never find it by searching for anything related to the issue.

Comment: Hmm, so someone was offended by that answer...oops.

Comment: Oh, definitely, it is very hard to find that post when these issues come up. Which is probably why it gets asked about often. I've almost reached to the point where I should just favorite the post, instead of hunting down...voter's profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's been flagged offensive, which incurs a temporary -1.

Answer (score 1):

Spam/Offensive and other automatic vote types behave differently now, in a way that presents correctly with vote counts.