# Is it appropriate to point out SQL Injection vulnerabilities in posts?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

My simple mind can't come to grips with the plethora of code snippets that get posted which are prone to SQL injection, yet here we are.

Is it considered a service to the community to point this fact out to those who post these?  That is, is it appropriate to comment on a post indicating that it's prone to SQL injection?

I'm not talking about [**whether or not to downvote posts with vulnerable code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136532/is-it-appropriate-to-down-vote-posts-containing-sql-injection-vulnerabilities/136533#136533), or [**catching it as a hot item**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/dont-forget-to-mention-sql-injection), or [**wondering what to do when I don't feel like answering with non-vulnerable code**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119822/ethics-for-sql-insert-queries-vulnerable-to-sql-injection/119879#119879).  I'm wondering about repeatedly leaving a [**civil and informative comment**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138173/etiquette-for-posting-civil-and-informative-comments) indicating the vulnerability, specific to SQL injection.

It seems to me that there is still enough ignorance of SQL injection to make commenting on it worthwhile if the poster shows no indication of knowing that it's a bad thing.  But I don't want to be *that guy* that just sits there whining that your code is vulnerable.

Comment: Yes... it's always important to do so. It's a sure-fire way to get the pundit badge as well...

Comment: I like how the PHP mysql_* even has something akin to a whole FAQ post about it, because it's so widely (and insecurely) used. Though not *directly* connected to SQL injection as such, that issue is often another fault of code that uses mysql_*.

Comment: This post should be migrated to meta.SO

Comment: @faintsignal why?  there are other sites that deal with programming

Comment: @psubsee2003 True, but in this instance the discussion seems to be centred around SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Of course it is appropriate.

Whenever you see something dangerous/stupid in posted code you should point it out, even if it  is not the thrust of the question.

It doesn't matter if you choose to do it in an answer (as an aside) or as a comment (to either a question or an answer).

When I see a question that has code that is clearly open to SQL Injection, I comment on it.

The maxim of Stack Overflow is "Make the Internet a better place" - pointing out SQL Injection is just a part of that.

We don't only answer questions - we try to educate and explain and make better developers.

Comment: Agreed. I would add: Don't just say "This is vulnerable"; *explain* the vulnerability; if possible give an example exploit. In my opinion the best way to learn about and understand these and other vulnerabilities is seeing how they can be exploited.

Comment: Good, that is what I was hoping.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. Because it still is a big problem.

Maybe add a self answered question about SQL injection. So there is a resource that can be used to link to.

Comment: Because there are no existing resources on SO that discuss what SQL injection is...